# PDO returning data from mysql database in a list

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have recently started to learn PHP as well as PDO. I'm having a trouble with returning data in a numeric list. I think i need a loop to numeric every row, but I do not how long the loop has to be. Probably I need to get how many rows are returned, but when I tried to do so, it was not working for me.

Now I have :

```
$query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM nariai');
    while($r = $query->fetch()) {
    echo $r['name'], $r['job'], '<br>';
}
```

I want to write a code which would make it look like :

> 1. Josh Policeman
> 2. Anthony Bussinesman

and so on...

Comment: And your question is? Maybe it would be helpful if you post your code and explain what it should do and what it actually does.

Comment: @honk made a change to my post. maybe now it is more understandable.

Comment: What PDO method are you using? fetchAll()? Do you have some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following code

```
$i = 1;
$query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM nariai');
while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $i.'.'.$r['name'], $r['job'], '<br>';
     $i++;
}
```